# Could someone recommend a db management tool that supports SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and is web-based?

Tags: database-recommendation, tools

Could someone recommend a db management tool that supports SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and is web-based? By 'web-based' I just mean it can be run in a browser locally or remotely.

Comment: I think this would be considered a shopping question if it weren't for the fact that so few of these (if any) exist.

Comment: This is a curious question. Browsers can't interact with databases directly, so the so that would need to be done on the server-side (like phpPgAdmin etc), but that wouldn't make much sense for SQLite which is not client-server. Can you explain your situation a bit more: why you need the tool and why it needs to run in a browser?

Comment: I suppose you want "free" as well?

Comment: Not necessarily free. I have these databases in the above 3 flavors and would like to use one tool to manage them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a remote desktop is an acceptable web-based solution, you could have [Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_overview.html) on a remote server that way you don't need the tool locally (*premium* is the cross-databases edition of the tool: it has `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `SQL Lite` and even `SQL Server`) .

But you would find cheaper/free if you simply install a tool per database type (e.g. [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), [Chive](http://www.chive-project.com), [phpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php?id=start), [SQLiteManager](http://www.sqlitemanager.org)).

Answer (score 0):

While not truly web based, you can start the dbWatch interface from a java webstart session. You can test this on our webpage (http://www.dbwatch.com/). It supports Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Sybase, PostgreSQL and Ingres. Other platforms will be supported in the future.

I work there, so you know :-)
-Chris

Comment: We appreciate you looking for appropriate questions on which to promote your product as well as you disclosing your affiliation with it.  However, if this is the ONLY reason you came to the site you should probably re-evaluate your reason for being here.